# How to dynamically increase the size of the arraylist in bucket sort?

Tags: java, sorting, bucket

I am getting this error when I attempt to dynamically increase the length of each bucket as I add elements.
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<ArrayList>

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
public float[] bucketSort(float[] array, int size) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> buckets = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int bucketIndex = (int)Math.floor(size*array[i]);
        buckets[bucketIndex].add(array[i]);                  // need help here
    } 

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int bucketLength = buckets[i].length;
        buckets[i] = insertionSort(buckets[i], bucketLength);
    }

    int arrayIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(intj = 0; j < buckets[i]; j++) {
            array[arrayIndex++] = buckets[i][j];
        }
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is not an array. Those are two different thing. You can't access `ArrayList` as if it was an array. `buckets[i]` is not a valid syntex. You should use `buckets.get(i)` instead.

Comment: Thank you.

Also, 

buckets.get(i) = insertionSort(buckets.get(i), bucketLength);

how do I assign the sorted array back into the bucket?

Comment: If inside of `insertionSort` you work on and sort the passed list (without copying it), then the bucket is already sorted, no need to reassign anything. Otherwise, you can use `buckets.set(i, yourSortedList)`

Comment: got it.
thanks a lot.